# Add 3 active class at once with javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have this code, and eberything works fine, and also add the active class like I want.
However, it's possible when i click on href='#tab58', add active in the first three classes at once?

If I click in `<a class="section_010" href='#tab58'></a>`

I Want to add active in this first class at once

```
<a class="section_010 active" href='#tab58'></a>
<a class="section_011 active" href='#tab58'></a>
<a class="section_012 active" href='#tab58'></a>
```

If I click on another href, work fine (only that item add active class)
[Code EXAMPLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1272/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.prov').each(function(){
            // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
            // which tab is active and it's associated content
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="prov">
    <a class="section_010" href='#tab58'></a>
    <a class="section_011" href='#tab58'></a>
    <a class="section_012" href='#tab58'></a>
    <a class="section_02" href='#tab60'></a>
    <a class="section_03" href='#tab61'></a>
    <a class="section_04" href='#tab62'></a>
    <a class="section_05" href='#tab63'></a>
    <a class="section_06" href='#tab64'></a>
    <a class="section_07" href='#tab65'></a>
    </ul>

    <div class="mapa_legenda">
        <div  id='tab58'> TEXT1</div>   
        <div  id='tab60'> TEXT2</div>   
        <div  id='tab61'> TEXT3</div>   
        <div  id='tab62'> TEXT4</div>   
        <div  id='tab63'> TEXT4</div>   
        <div  id='tab64'> TEXT4</div>   
        <div  id='tab65'> TEXT4</div>   
     </div>
```

---

**I update this code** [My Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1272/)

It's possible, when I click in "About MHG", "Workout Programs" OR "Fitness Tips". All of them , stay active at once. (you click in one of them, and all 3 stay active).

**I only want that for "About MHG", "Workout Programs" OR "Fitness Tips"
Anyone could help me please?**

```
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a class="menu2" href="#">About MHG</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu3" href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu4" href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu5" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu6" href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: can you put this into fiddle?

Comment: yes, I have this example http://jsfiddle.net/XA3Ua/

Comment: now what you want first three div should display?

Comment: The display div is Ok, I only need the active button. (use inspect element to see, please). I want, when you click in Tab1, the Tab 1
Same text Tab1, and Same Text Tab1 stay also active

Comment: Its possible something like, "if I click on #tab58, add ACTIVE to class section_010, class section_011, and class section_012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.
Please check 
http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1282/

Just add this part:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li a').each(function(i){
      if (i<3)$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, that I edit

I add active class, on both 3 first itens like you want.
Just using:

```
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $('a.menu2').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$('a.menu2').click(function(){
    $('a.menu2').removeClass("active");
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $('a.menu2').addClass("active");
});
```

Please check:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1264/